# flashing a microsd with a bootable OS that already has ssh opened up?

Tags: linux

i dont have spare mouse keyboard or microhdmi. But I do have an ethernet cable. Therefore I need to access and control the board with SSH. Is there a way to achieve this with preconfigured SSH? server?

Comment: Pi Imager advanced options will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and run Raspberry Pi Imager from the website:

[Raspberry Pi Software](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/)

Select which type of Pi you have, and then select an image (Raspberry Pi OS Lite is probably the right answer if you're using it headless, finally select where to write the image.  When you hit Next, it'll ask you if you want to configure the image, you can set the username, password and enable ssh from there.